# RDP permanent connection problems

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, remote-desktop, remote-connection

i have problems with my RDP connection to my VPS!
I have Win 7 Home Premium 64Bit version on my local pc and try to have an stable connection for a couple of hours to my Win 2008 r2 VPS !

The problem is that my connection drops after a couple of minutes of inactivity!
I would like to have the RDP open on my desktop and even if i don't work on the current RDP connection it should stay connected for hours (the connection is important cause i am running an Macro script which needs the connection)!

I have tried to add an "MaxIdleTime" QWORD 64 Bit file to the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/POLICIES/MICROSOFT/WINDOWS NT/Terminal Services) with an value of  21600000 and log off and log in again but it did not change anything!
I have read somewhere that i have to turn off Win Firewall, i have tried this also for an test but it did not change anything!

I have no idea what to do??
Perhaps you have some helpful tips!

Thanks

Comment: Well,finaly that did not help either!
My local machine lost connection after 15 minutes or so!
I've tried to build an permanent connection from one VPS to another via RDP and it did work without a problem!
It must be something with Win 7 !
Anybody here have an idea what it might be??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> To specify timeout and reconnection settings for a remote session
>
> On the RD Session Host server, open Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration. To open Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration,
>   click Start, point to Administrative Tools, point to Remote Desktop
>   Services, and then click Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.
>
> Under Connections, right-click the name of the connection, and then click Properties.
>
> In the Properties dialog box for the connection, on the Sessions tab, select the following options as necessary:
>
> Select the Override user settings check box, and then set timeout settings for End a disconnected session, Active session limit,
>   and Idle session limit.
>
> Select the Override user settings check box, and then select one of the following reconnection settings: Disconnect from session or
>   End session.
>
> Click OK. Changes to timeout and reconnection settings are not applied to sessions that are connected when the change is made. The
>   changes will take effect the next time the user establishes a new
>   connection to the RD Session Host server.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc754272.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Dave, thank you soooo much!
I would like to vote up your answer but i have not enough reputation,sorry about that :( !

A couple of days ago i have done that what you have described too but it did not work for some reason, perhaps i have tried both settings (local machine and VPS) separately but not both settings at the same time, who knows?

However, no i have a permanent connection, i will have to test it over the next couple of days for longer periods but now at least it works for 20 minutes!

Thanks you very very much!!!

Bye

Comment: just a quick note/question, this seems to work for one active RDP connection but i have multiple open at the same time!
from what i see just the first one is permanently connected and the others disconnect after a certain amount of minutes!
i have the same setup on all VPS now and it still won't work!
should i create another MaxIdleTime QWORD files in the registry (equal to the amount of RDP connections i have up at the same time) or won't it help?
i am curious why just one works?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you are connecting with unique usernames? If so, this will have to be done for each username, but, via Group Policy you can apply it system wide (but I cannot remember where this is) @user3329033

Comment: well,each connection has the same username but it is a unique VPS with uique IP, username is on all VPS the same - always administrator!
so you mean i should try to add more MaxIdleTime QWORD files and see if it helps?

Thank you sooooo much for your support Dave!!!

Comment: problem is that i can't add another MaxIdleTime file cause there can't be two! On the other hand, i am not sure if can edit the Group Policy on Win 7 ? i guess it does not support it or there was something like that! thanks

Comment: I was talking about edting group policy on the VPS

Comment: ok,i will check that out, i guess you mean i should edit them on the one that disconnects or do you mean on all VPS even the one that works now? Thanks

Comment: well,to be honest...it must be some settings on my local machine cause one server can not know that i am connected to another one and drop the connection.